# multiple conditionally required fields in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a schema with a property that is required based if an enumeration matches some value. This works fine.

```
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "not" : {
          "properties": {
            "other-val": { "enum" : ["ABC"]}
          }
        }
      },
      { "required": ["ABC-detail"] } 
    ],
```

But, I'm trying to add a second field, `DEF-detail`, based on if the `other-value` enum is "DEF". I am not sure how to chain these dependencies up. I tried putting multiple `oneOf`s insde an `allOf`, but I can't add multiples of the same key to it.

Answer (score 1):

That pattern is called "implication". You can easily declare more than one implication by combining them with `allOf`.

```json
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "not": {
            "properties": {
              "other-val": { "const": "ABC" },
            },
            "required": ["other-val"]
          }
        },
        { "required": ["ABC-detail"] }
      ]
    },
    ... another implication ...,
    ... another implication ...
  ]
}
```

If you are using draft-07 or later, you also have the `if`/`then` which is just a little syntactic sugar for implication.

```json
{
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "other-val": { "const": "ABC" }
    },
    "required": ["other-val"]
  },
  "then": { "required": ["ABC-detail"]
}
```

This pattern can be combined using `allOf` in the same way as implication.

Answer (score 0):

A set of conditions in a `oneOf` works. But I don't think this excludes a `DEF` from having an `abc-thing`, for example, but this is OK in my case.

```
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "properties": {"other-val": {"enum": ["ABC"]}},
        "required": ["abc-thing"]
      },
      {
        "properties": {"other-val": {"enum": ["DEF"]}},
        "required": ["def-thing"]
      },  
      {
        "properties": {"other-val": {"enum": ["GHI"]}},
        "required": ["ghi-thing"]
      },            
      {
        "not": {"properties": {"other-val": {"enum": ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]}}}
      }
    ],
```

Comment: This will work, but the error messages you get when using this pattern are terrible to the point of being useless. See my answer for a better (albeit more verbose) approach.